# Fill a form on a alert box with typescript and angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I fill a form (and its element) with typescript?

I'm working with Ionic and I need to access a page that ask me username and password on an alert box, with an ok button. How can I fill the element of this form and then press ok without user pressing or typing anything?

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please read [ask] before submitting a question and be sure to provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

field binding by using [(ngModel)]

myfile.component.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myInput"/>
<button id="myButton"/>
```

myfile.component.ts

```
public myInput: string ="";
    myInput="here we go!";
    clickButton(){
     let btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
     btn.click();
    }
```